# Initialising a useReducer with async data in a hook

Tags: reactjs

First, some context.

I have a functional component which loads data asynchronously.

```
const { error, loading, data, getAllData } = useData(); // useData is a custom hook abstracting Context API

if (error) return <Error error={error} />;
if (!data || loading) return <LinearProgress />;

{/* etc .. */}
```

so `data` is loaded async which means initially it is undefined but when the async loading finishes it gets some real value.

Now I need to show the data in a table and for the table I want to abstract away some logic into a hook.

So I end up having

```
const { error, loading, data, getAllData } = useData();
const tableCtrl = useTable(data);

if (error) return <Error error={error} />;
if (!data || loading) return <LinearProgress />;
```

In `useTable.ts` I have

```
export function useTable(initialItems: TableItem[]): TableCtrl {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, {
        items: initialItems,
        selectedItems: [],
        allSelected: false
    });

    return {
        ...state,
        deleteItem: (itemToDelete: TableItem) =>
            dispatch({ type: 'delete_item', item: itemToDelete }),
        selectAll: () => dispatch({ type: 'select_all' }),
        selectNone: () => dispatch({ type: 'select_none' }),
        select: (item: TableItem) => dispatch({ type: 'select', item }),
        deselect: (item: TableItem) => dispatch({ type: 'deselect', item })
    };
}
```

Now I'm pretty sure you can spot the problem, but the `initialData` which the hook uses to create the `useReducer` is `undefined` and it never really updates it. So when the real data "arrives" it won't update the state of the hook.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

That's interesting question. Because hook of `React.useReducer` is only take the initial value once, then it will maintain the state itself without setting value again.

So the idea is quite simple. You just simply set the your state again via the `dispatch` function you exported every time your `data` has been changed. Here is the idea snippet:

Let's create a exported function to update your state in `useTable.ts`:

```js
return {
 setData: data => dispatch(/* This is where you set your state again */)
}
```

Now call `setData` right your `data` changed in your main file:

```js
const { setData, ...others } = useTable(data);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (data) {
   // This will sync your state with the latest data
   setData(data);
  }
}, [data])
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing similar as @tmhao2005 mentioned. My final solution looks like the following.
I wanted to do this to be able to decouple table logic (selection, deletion, etc..) from presentation logic. So that I can create a generic-table'ish component (not showcased in the example below)

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableCell,
  TableRow,
  Link
} = MaterialUI;

// to mimic async loading of data
function useData() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setData([1, 2, 3]), 0);
  }, []);

  return {
    data,
    deleteByIndex: (idx) => {
      // some random function to mutate the state
      setData(data.filter((_, index) => idx !== index));
    }
  };
}

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "init":
      return { ...state, items: action.items };
    default:
      throw new Error("unknown action");
  }
}

function useTable(initialItems) {
  const isFunctionCreator = React.useMemo(
    () => typeof initialItems === "function",
    [initialItems]
  );

  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, {
    items: isFunctionCreator ? null : initialItems,
    selectedItems: [],
    allSelected: false
  });

  const data = isFunctionCreator ? initialItems() : null;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isFunctionCreator && data) {
      dispatch({ type: "init", items: data });
    }
  }, [isFunctionCreator, data]);

  return {
    ...state
  };
}


const App = () => {
  const { data, deleteByIndex } = useData();
  const ctrl = useTable(() => data);

  if (!data) return <div>Loading</div>;

  return (
    <TableContainer>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Item</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center" size="small"></TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {ctrl.items &&
            ctrl.items.map((item, idx) => (
              <TableRow key={item}>
                <TableCell>{item}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center" size="small">
                  <Link onClick={() => deleteByIndex(idx)}>Delete</Link>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}

// React bootstrap
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: The way of watching the initial value at your hook is also not a bad idea I guess :)