# pass a useReducer state to another useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am trying to create a search for a simple todo-app, instead of trying to manage the filtered states throught the reducer that handles the todos, [I was told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003553/redux-what-is-the-correct-way-to-filter-a-data-array-in-reducer) to set another useReducer instead and then manage the filters throught that reducer, tho, on Redux (which is my reference based of) they use mapStateToProps.

The problem is that when I pass my state that comes from the todos useReducer down to my filter reducer state, it wont update as I change the reducer. And it is expected. My initial value is my todo's state (whose an empty array) and it will always be even when new todos are added to the list.

well, whats the ideal aproach in this case?

code:

[image]

Comment: I would get rid of the `useReducer` in the `Search` and move the logic in to a `useEffect`

Comment: The problem looks fairly related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63632841/initialising-a-usereducer-with-async-data-in-a-hook/63633920

Comment: @tmhao2005 indeed is very similar, thanks for showing. But the answer I quite hard to grasp in a way I could apply onto my code. Could you please edit the answer to be more generic so people with similar issue could grasp better?

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress i achieve that this way: `useEffect(() => {const filteredTodos = todos.filter((todo) => todo.text.includes(search));}, [todos, search]);
` where `search` is a useState state.

Comment: Alright... i got it. But how confusing is it?

Answer (score 0):

Shaping your state is up to you -- shape it in a way that works best. Both Redux and React are unopinionated about that. If it makes sense to put those slices of state together, do that. With `useReducer`, think about storing the entire state for a component in it vs breaking it up. I look at `useReducer` as the alternative for a bunch of `useState` statements.

In the case of Redux, if a filter in a reducer needs to filter data in another reducer, _do that in the component, e.g.,

`const filterdData = rawDataState.filter(x => x.someProperty === filterState)`